# Why are Java substrings bad?

Tags: java

I have recently started using Java for the first time (I used to primarily use C, C++ or Assembly before this) and ran into substrings. I know that Java characters and strings take up at least double the space the character or string should take. But why are substrings bad? I have been advised by a lot of people to avoid them if possible on processing intensive platforms but Strings are used everywhere in web services which can be very processing intensive, so I am curious as to why so many people have this opinion.

Comment: java characters and strings take up exactly as much space as a character or string should take.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with substrings.  We are not in the business of calming anyone's unsubstantiated worries, much less if we first have to guess what these worries are.  Substantiate your worries, and then we might bother shooting them down.

Comment: Why don't you ask your advisers? (I mean I never heard of such advise)

Comment: Char takes up 2 bytes in Java even though a char can be stored in 1 byte

Comment: @CarefulNow That's not true. We have unicode and several different languages with different writing systems, there's no way you can fit a single unicode character into 8 bits.

Comment: Java `char` is something completely different from the C `char`.

Comment: @CarefulNow No it can't. Java uses UTF-16 representation which requires at least 2 bytes per character (sometimes more depending on the character which is the real gotchya with chars)

Comment: Ahh Unicode I'm still thinking in Ascii. Cheers @Kayaman

Answer (score 5):

This may be related to how `substring()` was previously implemented. In earlier Java versions calling `substring()` on a long `String` would keep the original `String` in memory (they would share the internal `char[]`). This can cause memory issues if the original Strings are kept around in memory unnecessarily.

In Java 8 this is no longer the case (the internal `char[]` is copied) and you can freely take substrings of even long `Strings`.